# Add an arraylist to a tab

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabcontainer

Is it possible to add an array, or arraylist to a tab. So I could do something like:

```
  ArrayList test = tabControl1.Controls.ArrayList();
```

or something along these lines.

I need this because I will have many tabs and they will have to remember a set amount of pages that are read from a file at launch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should try something like [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: My tabs contain a web browser. However I need to store some webpage address's for each tab so it would make it 1000% easier to add a collection to the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tag` property of each `TabPage` to store your list of pages.